# PayPal subscription : Changing next billing date

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, subscription, paypal-subscriptions

I want to change next billing date of existing subscription i.e. extend it by N days.
And I don't want to create new plan for it
Is there any way to achieve this?

I want to know if it's possible in paypal to change next billing date or not

Comment: ask paypal maybe?

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [Update Subscription](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_patch) patch API call to change the `start_time`.

You may need to first pause and then resume the subscription with the respective API calls.

I have not tested this, and it may not work. It is possible to override the `plan_id` with a custom `plan` object that has a different billing_cycle, but as far as I know setting a trial of a different total_cycles:1 and then auto resuming the regular billing cycle will not work. You would need to set a single billing cycle for the new period then after the first payment update it again to be the usual cycle.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cant update a payment that has already had at least one cycle complete.